# Google Analytics Add On in Google Spreadsheet Giving Server Error Message

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This morning on 7/12/2018, when I was running my daily Analytics report using Google Analytics Add On in Google Spreadsheet, I got this message: "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." Anybody seeing this message, I am seeing it for the first time. Tried to run the reports intermittently, still getting the same error. Want to know if its a system wide problem or is there anything off with my setting, which I have not changed at all.

Comment: I personally have no issues

Answer (score 0):

It's happening to me as well, as of this afternoon.